# PyCharm warns about string and bytes concatenation, but everything is string

Tags: python, string, pycharm, concatenation

PyCharm warns me about this:

```
days = os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), src))
day = days[0]
mystring = day.split('.')[0] + ';' + str(entering)
```

> expected type 'bytes', got 'str' instead

but everything seems to be str for me..
Anyway it works, but that warnings make me suspicious. Any hints?

**EDIT**
Adding more details: Pycharm is version 2019.3.3 in Linux. Entering is int, and src is a path coming from:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, description="")
p.add_argument('-src', dest='source', action='store', default='results', help='source path')

args = p.parse_args()
src = args.source
```

Comment: what are `src` and `entering`?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist replacing `src` and `str(entering)` with string literals reproduces this

Comment: seems like one of those "false positive" bugs in pycharm

Comment: @DeepSpace oh, yes, was able to reproduce.

the error is in the last line (...this might be useful information to add to the question).

Comment: Can't reproduce in pycharm community 2019.3.2 on Linux

Comment: hacky way to get rid of the message:: `day: str = days[0]` (but that really should not be necessary!)

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I added details

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `os.listdir` definition<sup>[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)</sup>, you can read section:

> If path is of type bytes (directly or indirectly through the PathLike interface), the filenames returned will also be of type bytes; in all other circumstances, they will be of type str.

I think this is indirect cause of `os.path.join` because it returns object implementing `PathLike` interface. I think PyCharm is assuming that `os.path.join` will return bytes somehow. Easiest way is just to convert to path to `str` using `str(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), src))` (*although it's already a str*)